# How to use D3 graphic inside popup mapbox?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graphics, popup, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to display a D3 graphic inside a popup of mapbox. I am not managing to make it because popup of mapbox is just accepting plain HTML.
Is there a way to make it? Like in the following pic where the graphic is inside the popup.

[image]

Comment: If one of the given answers solves the problem, please mark it that way.

Answer (score 2):

The way I was able to make it is using Chart.min.js. and jQuery.
[image]

Here is a [fiddle I have created to show you how to create a popup with a chart](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/24ykvm91/1/).

Relevant code is below.
First of all add your links to jquery and chart.js

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Then you add a canvas that will be managed by chart.js

```js
        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeOnClick: false })
            .setLngLat([-96, 37.8])
            .setHTML('<div class="chart"><canvas id="lineChart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas></div>')
            .addTo(map);
```

and then add the data sources, options and render the chart in the canvas

```js
   //this is fake data just for testing
   var areaChartData = {
      labels  : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label               : 'Digital Goods',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
          pointRadius          : false,
          pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
          pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
          data                : [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        },
        {
          label               : 'Electronics',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointRadius         : false,
          pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          data                : [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
      ]
    }

    //these are the options for testing
    var areaChartOptions = {
      maintainAspectRatio : false,
      responsive : true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines : {
            display : false,
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines : {
            display : false,
          }
        }]
      }
    }


    var lineChartCanvas = $('#lineChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var lineChartOptions = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartOptions)
    var lineChartData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartData)
    lineChartData.datasets[0].fill = false;
    lineChartData.datasets[1].fill = false;
    lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false

    var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas, { 
      type: 'line',
      data: lineChartData, 
      options: lineChartOptions
    })
```

If this answer solves your issue, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way other users will know it was the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

A Mapbox popup has a [getElement()](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup#getelement) method that you can use to get the DOM element for the popup.

You can then use [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) on the DOM element to get an element in your popup where you want to render the D3 graphic:

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map(...);

const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setLngLat([-96, 37.8])
  .setHTML('<svg class="popup-d3-svg" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;"></svg>')
  .addTo(map);
  
const svgElement = popup.getElement().getElementsByClassName('popup-d3-svg')[0];

const svg = d3.select(svgElement)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('background-color', 'black');

svg.append('line')
  .style('stroke', 'lightgreen')
  .style('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', 0)
  .attr('x2', 50)
  .attr('y2', 50);
```

Here is a working example using this technique: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljtx58pv/2/